# iPhone GameCenter won't showAchievments

Tags: iphone, game-center, achievements

So my problem is that after integrating gamecenter nicely into my iphone app, it won't show the achievements list!

The integration was a success I think because when I use the submitAchievement method, I do unlock achievements on the list. But I must look at the list from the GameCenter App on the iPhone, not within my own app as it doesn't work.
**ikuragames** first help me get the code right (thx you !!) but it still doesn't work ! :(

```
-(void)showAchievments
{
    //NSLog(@"showAchievments");
    GKAchievementViewController *achievements = [GKAchievementViewController alloc] init];
    if (achievements != nil)
    {
        achievements.achievementDelegate = self;
        [(EAGLView *)self.view achievmentsWillAppear];
        [self presentModalViewController:achievements animated:YES];
    }
}

- (void)achievementViewControllerDidFinish:(GKAchievementViewController *)viewController
{
    //NSLog(@"achievementViewControllerDidFinish");
    [glView achievmentsWillDisappear];
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

On debug mode, I can clearly see that each line or code are "processed" and not error whatsoever is displayed. BUT, nothing appears on my screen :(

Can you please help me ? ([here is some doc.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/GameKit_Guide/GameCenterOverview/GameCenterOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008304-CH5-SW7))

Comment: Are you logged into a sandbox GameCenter account?

Comment: I don't know, how can I check that?
I just checked on iTunes Connect and it says : "Game Center has been enabled for your app" and I got like ids and stuff for it. Acheivements have already been added so I can test unlocking them

Comment: After checking, I got a sandbox account. But that shouldn't be a problem right ?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer.

Turned out that the view controller I was sending `showAchievments` to was not the view controller I wanted.

I was doing something like:

```
[[myViewController sharedInstance] showAchievments];
```

But the `sharedInstance` method returned a brand-new, vanilla-initialised `myViewController`, and not the one I was already using.

Now it works perfectly, I hope this will help someone in the future.